# LARAVEL : Update stock value by the use of cart quantity

Tags: sql, laravel

when i try to update the values of my stocks, it keeps changing the same value for all the rows. This is my code:

```
public function subtractFromStocks(){
    $user_id=Auth::user()->user_id;
    $cartItems=DB::table('cart')
    ->join('stocks','stocks.stock_id','=','cart.stock_id')
    ->join('sizes','sizes.size_id','=','stocks.size_id')
    ->join('shoes','shoes.shoe_id','=','stocks.shoe_id')
    ->where('cart.user_id',$user_id)
    ->select('cart.stock_id as cart_stock_id','cart.quantity as cart_quantity','stocks.stocks as stocks_quantity')
    ->get();
    
    //$cartItems->decrement('stocks',$cartItems['cart_quantity']);
    foreach($cartItems as $cartItem)
    {
        $stocks=DB::table('cart')
        ->join('stocks','stocks.stock_id','=','cart.stock_id')
        ->join('sizes','sizes.size_id','=','stocks.size_id')
        ->join('shoes','shoes.shoe_id','=','stocks.shoe_id')
        ->where('cart.user_id',$user_id)
        ->update(['stocks.stocks'=> $cartItem->stocks_quantity - $cartItem->cart_quantity]);
    }
    


    return $this->deleteCartRecords();
    
}
```

Comment: Using join for record updates is not a good approach. Can you use relationship instead?

Comment: `$records = DB::table('cart')
        ->join('stocks','stocks.stock_id','=','cart.stock_id')
        ->join('sizes','sizes.size_id','=','stocks.size_id')
        ->join('shoes','shoes.shoe_id','=','stocks.shoe_id')
        ->where('cart.user_id',$user_id)->get();
dd($records);`

dump the records and see if it returns all the records or the records that you needed?

Comment: "user_id" did you build your own user table or change the user id column name???